# How do I find the range of a difficult function?

Tags: functions

I find it really hard to find the range. I usually substitute the x's with y and then solve for y, but it does not always work for me.  Do you have any advice?

Function in question:

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-2x}}{x}$$

Comment: The function I'm working on right now is f(x) = (e^(-2x)) / x.

Comment: What are the rules of the game? Is graphing allowed? Can you use a derivative? (that would make it lots easier).Any other pertinent info?

Comment: There's no easy trick.  Graph it - either by computer/calculator or by hand.  You can use calculus to find minima/maxima and where it is increasing/decreasing.

Comment: Think also about the limits as $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$ or any singularities.

Comment: The only rule is that we cannot use any aid such as calculators or computers. Everything else should be okay!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, since $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-\infty$, and since $x>0\implies f(x)>0$, it follows from the intermediate value theorem that $f\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)=(0,\infty)$.

On the other hand, $f|_{(-\infty,0)}$ attains its maximum at $-\frac12$ and it takes the value $-2e$ there. Furtermore,$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-\infty.$$So, $f\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)=(-\infty,-2e)$. So, the range of $f$ is $(-\infty,-2e)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The domain of the function is $D_f=\mathbf R^*$. Its derivative is $f'(x)=-\dfrac{(2x+1)\mathrm e^{-2x}}{x^2}$. It has the opposite sign of the sign of $2x+1$, hence the function is

- increasing on the interval $\bigl(-\infty,-\frac12\bigr]$,
- decreasing on $\bigl[-\frac12, 0\bigr)$ and on $(0,+\infty]$.

Thus $f$ has a local maximum, $-2\mathrm e$, at $x=-\frac12$.

There remains to calculate the limits at $0, -\infty$ and $+\infty$; Can you finish the computations?